# IN SQL count after group by

Tags: sql, database, count, group-by

i want to count after `group by`, not the total line
just want to count by the categories 
after `group by` my result is like

```
course       lecturer
comp1111     Jim
comp1100     Jim
comp1100     Jim
infs2321     Jess
infs2321     Jess
econ1222     Helen
```

my result after count should be

```
lecturer    count
Jim          3
Jess         2
Helen        1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why you want a group by after you have grouped. You get your desired result by doing just one group. Please have a look at this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/420d6/2/0) to see it working live.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`course` varchar(8), `lecturer` varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`course`, `lecturer`)
VALUES
    ('comp1111', 'Jim'),
    ('comp1100', 'Jim'),
    ('comp1100', 'Jim'),
    ('infs2321', 'Jess'),
    ('infs2321', 'Jess'),
    ('econ1222', 'Helen')
;

select
lecturer, count(*)
from
Table1
group by lecturer desc;

| LECTURER | COUNT(*) |
-----------|----------|--
|      Jim |        3 |
|     Jess |        2 |
|    Helen |        1 |
```

**EDIT:**

You don't need an extra table. To get the row with the largest count you can simply do

```
select
lecturer, count(*)
from
Table1
group by lecturer
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

for MySQL or

```
select top 1 
lecturer, count(*)
from
Table1
group by lecturer
order by count(*) desc;
```

for MS SQL Server. In my first answer I had `GROUP BY lecturer DESC` which is the same as `GROUP BY lecturer ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC` because in MySQL `GROUP BY` implies an `ORDER BY`.

If this is not what you want, be careful with using `MAX()` function. When you simply do for example

```
select
lecturer, max(whatever)
from
Table1
group by lecturer;
```

you don't necessarily get the row with holding the max of whatever.

You can also do

```
select
lecturer, max(whatever), min(whatever)
from
Table1
group by lecturer;
```

See? You just get the value returned by the function, not the row belonging to it. For examples how to solve this, please refer to this [manual entry](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html).

I hope I didn't confuse you now, this is probably more than you wanted to know, because above is especially for groups. I think what you really want to do is simply ordering the table the way you want, then pick just one row, like mentioned above.

Comment: ooohh so when i do count(*) after group by lecturer, is it count by different lecturer automatically??

Comment: Yes, you get the count for each different lecturer.

Comment: thank u very much. and if i want to get the row with largest count, that is , 'Jim 3'. i cant use max(count(*) directly. do i must to create another table then obtain from Table1?

Comment: @CherryPeng Updated my answer for a detailed answer.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Feel free to accept my answer :) [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/about) how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It might work

```
SELECT LECTURER, COUNT(*) 
FROM 
(SELECT LECTURER, COURSE
FROM TABLE
WHERE 
GROUP BY LECTURER, COURSE )
GROUP BY LECTURER;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to this command in mysql

============================

```
select
lecturer, count(*)
from
Course_detail
group by lecturer desc;
```